# Uncaught ReferenceEror: nonExistentVariable is not defined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

```
const CounterStike = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = (e) => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  console.log(incrementCounterr)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
      <p>Counter: {counter}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CounterStike
```

Getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: nonExistentVariable is not defined
I have tried to resolve it by mine but nothing works

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am getting this error, I cant see any error in my code

Comment: The comment above the line causing the error says “introducing a bug”, that’s a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the  `console.log(nonExistentVariable)` line, as you have not defined this variable anywhere in your example.